Continuity of functions from a general topological space into $\mathbb{R^n}$

Consider the map
$$f: S^1 \times I /S^{1} \times \{1\} \rightarrow D^2$$
defined by $f(\theta,t) = (1-t)e^{i \theta}$. Then $f$ is a continuous function because it is the product of two continuous functions. Now it is clear that $f$ is surjective once we write down a complex number in $D^2$ in polar form.
Refer: Prove that the cone over $S^1$ is homeomorphic to $D^2$

If the domain were some subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$, then the statement is completly clear to me. I guess maybe it is presumed that the cone homemorphic to some subset $\mathbb{R^n}$?
Presuming my guess is true, I tried going further. It's quite easy to check that both the cylinder is compact and disc is hausdorf, from that, it suffices to simply give a continous bijection to prove homemorphism. I choose my bijection as the same function from the question $f( (\cos \theta, \sin \theta) , t) = (1-t)(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$... but now I am entirely confused as to how to prove continuity.
We have that the open sets in ${D}^2$ are inherited from the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ as $U_{\mathbb{R}^2} \cap D^2$, and then open sets on $ S^1 \times I /S^{1} \times \{1\} $ are the subsets $U$ of it for which the preimage through the projection $\pi : S^1 \times I \to  S^1 \times I /S^{1} \times \{1\} $ is open in the product topology.
It seems like a mess to show that preimage is open through the direct application of the topological definition of continuity. Could someone advise maybe a simpler way?

The cone $CS^1 = S^1 \times I / S^1 \times \{1\}$ is a quotient space. Recall by the universal property of quotient spaces, if we have a continuous map $f:X \to Y$ such that $x \sim x'$ implies $f(x) = f(x')$, then this map descends to a continuous map $\bar f: X/_\sim \to Y$ given by $\bar f[x] = f(x)$.
View $S^1$ as $\mathbb R / 2\pi \mathbb Z$ to get a natural parameterisation of $S^1$ by its radial angle. Define $f:\mathbb R \times I \subset \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb D^2 \subset \mathbb R^2$ by $f(x,t) = (1-t)(\cos x, \sin x)$. This is a product of two continuous functions in each component which is why it is continuous (see this), but if this is hard to see, just note that it is actually differentiable. Now, $f(2\pi n x,t) = f(x,t)$ so $f$ descends to continuous map $\bar f: S^1 \times I \to D^2$. Furthermore, $\bar f(\theta,1) = 0$ for all $\theta \in S^1$ so $\bar f$ descends once again to a map $\tilde f: CS^1 \to D^2$.

How do you know that $f: S^1 \times I \to D^2$ is continous tho?

@CatharticEncephalopathy It is a product of two continuous maps which is always continuous. More generally, polynomials in several variables are always continuous and composing them with continuous maps gives a continuous map. Nevertheless, there is some paramterising/quotienting going on with the circle which makes it hard to see. So, I have spelt it out in the edited answer.
